# How do I programmatically obtain the version in JBoss AS 5.1?

Tags: java, jboss

Does anyone know how to programmatically obtain the server version number under JBossAS 5.1?

JBossAS 4.2 had `org.jboss.Version`, with `getMajor()` and `getMinor()` methods, but this doesn't seem to exist in 5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I chose to decompile the `Version` class from JBoss 4.2 to see what it was doing, and see if the result could be retrofitted into JBoss 5. The end result was to load the resource `/org/jboss/version.properties` into a `Properties` object, and then read out the `version.major` and `version.minor` properties from that. Beats me why they couldn't just leave the `Version` class in there, but there you go.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to get the Version Number. I thing the official way is using JMX as as described on their [Website](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/UsingTheRMIAdaptor), but for this the appserver has to reachable. The MBean to ask is *jboss.system:type=server*. You can even use the external shell skript twiddle for this:

```
%JBOSS_HOME%\bin>twiddle get jboss.system:type=Server VersionNumber
VersionNumber=5.1.0.GA
```

And here is the Code-Snippet from their Website (remote jmx):

```
MBeanServerConnection server = (MBeanServerConnection)new InitialContext().lookup("jmx/rmi/RMIAdaptor");
ObjectName on = new ObjectName("jboss.system:type=Server");
Object ver = server.getAttribute(on, "VersionNumber");
```

The other variant is using the package information of the loaded classes. If you load a class, like org.jboss.Main you are able to get the implementation version as specefied in the [JAR file spec](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html). Here  is a example:

```
    org.jboss.Main m=new Main();   //at least a jboss class loaded. not needed in the container
    Package p=Package.getPackage("org.jboss");
    System.out.println("Major=" + p.getImplementationVersion().split("\\.")[0]);
    System.out.println("Minor=" + p.getImplementationVersion().split("\\.")[1]);
```

**UPDATE**: added version number by package inspection.

Comment: That's very close to what I need, but for legacy reasons, I really need the distinct major and minor version numbers, rather than a combined string.