# How to get jboss7 version in java programatically through?

Tags: java, jboss

i have use j boss 4.2.2 to latest version.i have use java development kit 1.5 to 1.7 latest version all j boss version in get all java development kit. how to get j boss version in java code through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 5 there is a properties file: /org/jboss/version.properties where the keys version.major and version.minor looks for your case. Sust load the file to Properties and read. See link below:

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.jbossas/jboss-as-main/5.0.0.CR2/org/jboss/version.properties

This file has been kept also in jboss6.1

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.jbossas/jboss-as-main/6.1.0.Final/org/jboss/version.properties?av=f

I realized you asked for jboss7.... but I leave the work I did in case can be useful (it is anyway an approach valid for 5 and 6 versions)
For jboss7 I found two ways:

WAY 1
Checking out the code from github I **cannot find anymore this Versoin.properties** in the sources.
But I could find a Version.class which stores the version and release code name as properties; you can use Version.AS_VERSION to get what you want as you can see from the  source code:

```
    public class Version {
        public static final String AS_VERSION;
        public static final String AS_RELEASE_CODENAME;
        public static final int MANAGEMENT_MAJOR_VERSION = 1;
        public static final int MANAGEMENT_MINOR_VERSION = 4;
        public static final int MANAGEMENT_MICRO_VERSION = 0;

        static {
            InputStream stream =         Version.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF");
            Manifest manifest = null;
            try {
                if (stream != null)
                    manifest = new Manifest(stream);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

            String version = null, code = version;
            if (manifest != null) {
                version = manifest.getMainAttributes().getValue("JBossAS-Release-        Version");
        code = manifest.getMainAttributes().getValue("JBossAS-Release-Codename");
    }
    if (version == null) {
        version = "Unknown";
    }
    if (code == null) {
        code = "Unknown";
    }

    AS_VERSION = version;
    AS_RELEASE_CODENAME = code;
}
```

}

WAY2

Another option that I found googling but I didn't verify personally is going through JMX (perhaps you prefer this approach):

```
    ModelControllerClient client = ModelControllerClient.Factory.create(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9999);  
    ModelNode op = new ModelNode();  
    op.get(ClientConstants.OP).set("read-resource");  

    ModelNode returnVal = client.execute(op);  
    logger.info("release-version: " + returnVal.get("result").get("release-version").asString());  
    logger.info("release-codename: " + returnVal.get("result").get("release-codename").asString());
```

And from the jboss-admin command line interface, you can get the info from these commands:
/:read-attribute(name=release-version)
/:read-attribute(name=release-codename)

NOTE:

The source code are now under  git clone https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly.git (the jboss website still send to an outdated link)

Comment: I tried method #2, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial: https://community.jboss.org/thread/176932?start=0&tstart=0

or this: [How do I programmatically obtain the version in JBoss AS 5.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572185/how-do-i-programmatically-obtain-the-version-in-jboss-as-5-1)